# Change div width and height according to screen width and height

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<html><head>
<script src="js.js"></script>
<title></title>
<style>
#box
{
background:red;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="box"></div>

<script>
var x=$(window).width();
var y=$(window).height();
var a=x/2;
var b=y/2;

$(document).ready(function(){$("#box").css(width,a)});
$(document).ready(function(){$("#box").css(height,b});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the div width and height to vary on each screen size, but this code isn't working. Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't do this via relative values (like percent) in plain CSS?

Comment: I can do that, but currently I am searching for jquery code for the same. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need JS for that. Use that CSS:

```
#box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  /* left: 25%; */ /* uncomment if you want to center horizontally */
  /* top: 25%; */ /* uncomment if you want to center vertically */
  position: absolute;
}
```

Working sample: http://jsbin.com/eZUkADe/1/edit

If you have to achieve that with jQuery, here you are:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x=$(window).width();
    var y=$(window).height();
    var a=x/2;
    var b=y/2;

    $("#box").css('width', a);
    $("#box").css('height', b);
});
```

Working sample: http://jsbin.com/UXAPUSo/1/edit

Comment: Can you pls give me a jquery alternative

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x=$(window).width();
    var y=$(window).height();
    var a=x/2;
    var b=y/2;

    $("#box").css({width:a+'px',height:b+'px'});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be answered using vw/vh, [see here](http://quirksmode.org/css/viewport.html). Otherwise, use simple % values, by setting your body css to `width:100%;height:100%;`, you can then use % values for any child components to give them a reactive size.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about `vh` and `vw` yet. But you should keep in mind, that there is a difference in `50%`and `50vw`, when there are margin left (for example in the body) -- Sample:  http://jsbin.com/uNOCavaZ/2/edit

Comment: Absolutely- the question was pretty broad so it was hard to determine the requirement, hence two solutions which may be appropriate, albeit different in their nature